# How to encode a POST Policy in golang - browser based uploads to amazon S3?

Tags: post, go, amazon-s3, base64

I am trying to upload a image file to amazon s3. The setup is as follows:

Web server: golang
Front-end: simple html form for testing

In reference with this document : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

I referred to the example provided in the above document and tried this:
 http://play.golang.org/p/3zn5fSDasK

```
  package main

  import "fmt"
  import "encoding/base64"

  func main() {
         bytePolicy := []byte(`{ 
                    "expiration": "2013-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
                    "conditions": [
                             {"bucket": "examplebucket"},
                             ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
                             {"acl": "public-read"},
                             {"success_action_redirect": "http://acl6.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
                             ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
                             {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
                             ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
                             {"x-amz-credential":"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
                             {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
                             {"x-amz-date": "20130806T000000Z" }
                      ]
                  }`)
        fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytePolicy))
 }
```

The result I got with this

```
   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
```

The base 64 encoded policy which is on link of amazon tutorial:

```
   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
```

Why my base64 encoded policy doesn't match with that of Amazon's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because the 2 JSON source texts which produce those base64 strings have different indentation and different content as seen below (they are not equal char-by-char).

Decode both of the base64 strings, and you will see the differences. You can do that either with a program (not necessarily Go), or simply use an online service like [this one](https://www.base64decode.org/).

You shouldn't worry about indentation, it doesn't matter in JSON. But when you encode a text using Base64, that encodes all characters of the source including spaces and tabs used to indent, so different indentation will result in different Base64 encoded forms.

But comparing the 2 decoded JSON, there are also other differences:

First one:

```
"expiration": "2013-08-06T12:00:00.000Z"
"success_action_redirect": "http://acl6.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"
```

2nd one:

```
"expiration": "2013-08-07T12:00:00.000Z"
"success_action_redirect": "http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"
```

---

The complete decoded JSON texts:

The first one:

```
{ 
                        "expiration": "2013-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
                        "conditions": [
                                 {"bucket": "examplebucket"},
                                ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
                                 {"acl": "public-read"},
                                 {"success_action_redirect": "http://acl6.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
                                ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
                                {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
                                ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

                                {"x-amz-credential":"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
                                {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
                               {"x-amz-date": "20130806T000000Z" }
                          ]
                    }
```

And the 2nd one:

```
{ "expiration": "2013-08-07T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20130806T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, as I am trying to create this policy and later sign this using my amazon access key. How do I ensure that my indentation and the indentation which will be generated at Amazon's end will be same? So that, ultimately, my signature matches with that of Amazon's.

Comment: @TriptiR Just use the formatting what you see in Amazon's text (e.g. 2 spaces for indenting, arrays in one line, space after `':'` and `','` etc.).

Comment: I found one issue with in the JSON policy itself(1 parameter was different). I tried something else after your suggestion, I decoded the original base64 string from amazon tutorial by using [link](base64encode.org) and re-encoded that using my program. Though I cant see any difference in indentation now, the base64 encoded strings are still different.

Comment: @TriptiR Edited the answer, there are 2 differences besides indentation.

Comment: Thanks, as it was unsuitable to change the question itself. Still, I couldn't get it working even after correcting this. In steps for creating a POST policy, there is a requirement - "Create a policy using UTF-8 encoding". I believe, I am missing something at this point. How to ensure that my JSON-policy is created using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @TriptiR That just means the JSON text describing the policy, it needs to be converted/represented as UTF-8 byte sequence when applying base64 encoding. But this is how Go stores strings in memory exactly.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the program with that understanding, but I guessed that I might me missing something about UTF-8!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92448/discussion-between-tripti-r-and-icza).

Comment: @TriptiR I don't have access to chat where I am now. If you have a specific new question, ask a new question.

Comment: No issues! The question is exactly same. Even after keeping the indentation proper, I am getting two different base64 encoded strings. This time I am retrieving the JSON Policy from the example base64 policy itself. Should I ask this as a different question or update this question itself?

Comment: @TriptiR If you still have 2 different base64 texts, the procedure should be the same: decode both and then you can compare the decoded JSON texts to find the differences.